# Printing to PDF in Landscape Orientation

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code I am using to print to PDF and it works fine> I had to add some columns and now need t print in landscape but cannot seem to get it to work.

Can someone help me with this tweak?

```
Sub PrintRentalToPDF()
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Mortgage1"
Dim PrintRng As Range
Dim pdfile As String
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
'Setting range to be printed
Set PrintRng = Range("C5:M15")
sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
pdfile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(InitialFileName:=sPath & "Rental Income Calc", _
    FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
    Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")
Filename = pdfile
If Filename = False Then
Exit Sub
Else
PrintRng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=pdfile, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False
Call MsgBox(pdfile & " file has been saved!")
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Mortgage1"
End If
Range("D6").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it do *instead* of work?  Maybe you need to reset the page setup Print Area?

Comment: it prints portrait

Comment: wait sorry I just realized that it does print landscape but it doesn't  fit the columns

Comment: Then maybe the Print Area is the problem

Comment: I was able to fix it with : ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1